# Setting GWT celltable data from presenter

Tags: gwt, celltable

I am new for GWT. I would like to know, is it possible to set the cell table content from the **GWT Presenter**? Is it OK to set the cell table data from the view itself and still following the MVP Pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse with GWT presenter and it's pattern. As you know  that GWT presenter is contract to communicate between View and Model. it's good to write server **dispatch** code and **event bus** code in presenter and setting of data for GWT widgets in View itself.

After fetching celltable data from model to presenter, using `dispatch.execute` method. In `onSuccess` method,  call a method which set data in celltable.

- Define one method which set celltable data  in View Interface

  ```
    public interface MyView  extends View
      {
       void setCellTableData(List<Data> dataList);
      }
  ```

  it will implemented in view class, write a code that set data of celltable there.
- In presenter, **onSuccess** method set data like

  ```
  dispatch.execute(new GetDataAction(),
      new AsyncCallback<GetDataActionResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

          }
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(List<Data> result) {
               getView().setCellTableData(result);
          }   
          };
      });
  ```

Comment: I am using AsyncDataProvider for setting the data to cell table, in that case how do i set the list? Also i am using RequestBuilder to fetch the data from server.

Comment: write AsyncDataProvider setdata method in view. and pass data list in that method from presenter.

Comment: i have set the dataprovider, but the cell table is not displaying the data that is fetched from server. i am using RequestBuilder to fetch data from the server. At the time of setting the dataprovider in the presenter, request call back is not completed. how do i solve this?.

Comment: set dataprovider after request call back completed. add code what you tried?

Comment: in the call back function i called tableView.setDataProvider(dataprovider); in tableview the setDataProvider will set the  dataProvider.addDataDisplay(celltable);

Answer (score 1):

**View is only to render the UI.**

It should not hold the state of a `specific domain object`.

All `view` rendering business logic should be part of `Presenter` layer.

[Better practices of MVP.](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/gwt-best-practices/).

[Use and Maintaining Different layers in MVP.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25491/Model-View-Presenter-And-Its-Best-Practices)